# Passing Data in Angular2 to Child Component

Tags: angular, components

Hello I have a little problem passing data from a parent Component to a child component controller.

Thats the markup code of my parent Component `parent.component.html`

```
<element [mydata]="Value"></element>
```

With this I set mydata with an value.

I set this value using @Input in my child controller

```js
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'element',
    templateUrl: './element.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./element.component.scss'],
})

export class ElementComponent implements OnInit {

    @Input() public mydata:string;

    ngOnInit() {
        console.log(this.mydata);
    }
}
```

I get an undefined in the console, but why?

Comment: does `Value` gets populated from Ajax?

Comment: No, this works for me `<element [mydata]="value">{{value}}</element>` but how can I use this variable in the constructor?

Comment: why you want to get `value` inside constructor.. you should use lifecycle event...

Comment: At the moment I load an JSON from the constructre and I need an different jsonfilename. So I will pass the filename trough the component.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably a async problem, as it seems you are getting the data from json, which is probably fetched via http or something. The undefined is probably caused by that view is rendered before the data actually has been retrieved, which would throw an undefined error.

Try to set a condition, that the child component won't be rendered until it actually has a value:

```
<element *ngIf="value" [mydata]="value"></element>
```

And keep the current setup that you have been suggested from other answer, i.e:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'element',
    templateUrl: './element.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./element.component.scss'],
})


export class ElementComponent implements OnInit {

@Input() public mydata:string;

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log(this.mydata);
  }
}
```

Hope this helps!